# Copying CloudKit records from one record zone to another?

Tags: cloudkit

I am working on an app that will store a relatively small set of records to the CloudKit public database. Each user of the app will read those records but not update them. Along with this app, I am creating a companion app that I and a small group of administrators will be able to use to update records in that public database.

I have the basic operations of the administrator application working using basic CloudKit operations. I am now trying to implement a feature that requires multiple record types to be changed together. If an app user were to get one of those updated records and not the others, their system would be in an inconsistent state so I'd like to avoid that situation.

The ideal solution to this would be for the administrator application to submit the changes to all related records with a single `CKModifyRecordsOperation`, and to set the `atomic` property of that operation to `true`. Unfortunately, the CloudKit public database's default record zone does not support atomic operations and custom record zones are not supported in the public database. Therefore, there does not seem to be any way to atomically apply changes to the public CloudKit database.

As a workaround, I was considering the use of a private database that the administrator app would use. That database could have a custom record zone that supported I need atomic operations. However, that doesn't help me get the completed records copied over to the public database.

I am wondering if there is any supported way to tell CloudKit to copy a set of records from one record zone to another. I suspect there is no way to do this, but I'm hoping that I'm missing something.

Assuming there is no directly-supported way to do this in CloudKit, does anyone have suggested design changes that would allow me to make data available to my app users via the public CloudKit database in some way that supports atomic updates to multiple records?

Thanks

Comment: I would do it as follows: Every record has an additional attribute which indicates "whether and/or starting from when" the record is the one to be read. This could be a date or a simple version number. Somewhere else in your database you store which identifier should be used to read the records.This means you have time to update ( better to say insert the new set of records) - once you are finished you switch to the new set ( and could delete the old versions). Does this fit to your requirements?